# map input field name to array of input field value as indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I have the following input fields:

```
<input name='223' type='number' class='form-control score' value='70'>
<input name='224' type='number' class='form-control score' value='65'>
<input name='225' type='number' class='form-control score' value='87'>
```

What I want is to make the 'name' attribute as index of each 'value' in JavaScript for ajax posting. i.e get values as single array, map the names as the array indexes

```
Something like this:
array (
[223] => 70
[224] => 65
[225] => 87
)
```

Comment: `const scores = document.querySelectorAll('.score');` to get all input elements. Iterate that collection, and assign property => value to an object (not an array) on each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method to accumulate the inputs values and names to an object with key as input name and value as input value.

```js
const result = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]')].reduce((acc, i) => ({...acc, [i.name]: i.value}), {})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<input name='223' type='number' class='form-control score' value='70'>
<input name='224' type='number' class='form-control score' value='65'>
<input name='225' type='number' class='form-control score' value='87'>
```

It's a bad practice to use `array` data structure with keys as a random numbers, the array is designed to have sequence of keys starting with 0

```js
let array = [];

// It's a bad practice to use random index as a key for an array.
// this will create a 222 item with undefined as a value and the item number 223 with 222
array["222"] = 222;

console.log(array)
```

Using Array this way causes a memory leak.

Comment: I think he needs an array of objects, not a single object!

Comment: He didn't say he need an array of objects.

Comment: In my opinion, this is an helpful answer. Maybe you can add how it would reduce to an array and name its disadvantage? `.reduce((acc, i) => {acc[i.name] = i.value; return acc}, [])`

Comment: @Matthias, Thanks for your opinion, but the array doesn't design for getting random key values, it is designed for a sequence of indexes starting from 0, maybe the OP was confused about the data structure type he need.

Comment: @Matthias, I think the OP is confused between the data structure of javascript and PHP.

Comment: I think the closest thing to what he wrote, is an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

You may want an array of objects with `key: value` corresponding to `name` and `score` attribute of each element. One way to achieve this is with `array.map()`

```js
const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".score"))
const indexes = inputs.map(item => ({[item.name]: item.value}))
console.log(indexes)
```

```html
<input name='223' type='number' class='form-control score' value='70'>
<input name='224' type='number' class='form-control score' value='65'>
<input name='225' type='number' class='form-control score' value='87'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using array or object

If you use array for this it will create multiple empty values because the name in your html starts from `223`

```
var res = []
document.querySelectorAll('.score').forEach(d=>{
res[d.name] = d.value
})
console.log(res[223]) // 70
console.log(res[224]) // 65
// The res value will looks like [,,,,,,,,,,,70,65,87]
```

You can achive the same thing with object also

```
var res1 = {}
document.querySelectorAll('.score').forEach(d=>{
res1[d.name] = d.value
})
console.log(res1[223]) // 70
console.log(res1[224]) // 65
// The sample res1 value looks like {'223':70,'224':65,'225':87}
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than an Array, I'd suggest using an Object as numeric indices on an Array will create an Array-entry at that index, leading to a very sparse, and mostly empty but very large, Array.

One approach is as below:

```js
// helper utitilies, largely to reduce typing in larger projects;
// caching a reference to document:
const D = document,
  // an alias for querySelectorAll() that accepts an Element as
  // a context within which to search for the supplied selector,
  // defaulting to document:
  get = (sel, ctx = D) => ctx.querySelector(sel),
  // similar to the above, but an alias for querySelectorAll(),
  // and here we convert the NodeList returned from querySelectorAll()
  // into an Array in order to use Array methods:
  getAll = (sel, ctx = D) => [...ctx.querySelectorAll(sel)],
  // simple function to take a selector, retrieves the elements
  // matching that selector and then iterates over the Array of
  // Element Nodes:
  collate = (sel) => getAll(sel).map(
  // using an Arrow function along with destructuring assignment to
  // retrieve the 'name' and 'value' properties of the Element, and
  // passing those into the function body:
  ({
    name,
    value
  }) => {
    // here we return the Object formed from the name variable,
    // and supplying the value property of the Element as the
    // property-value:
    return {
      [name]: value
    }
  }),
  // calling the function on all <input> elements (adjust the selector
  // for more precise control):
  nameAndValues = collate('input'),
// this could also benefit from being converted into JSON:
  nameAndValuesJSON = JSON.stringify(nameAndValues);
  
  console.log(nameAndValues);
  console.log(nameAndValuesJSON);
```

```html
<input name='223' type='number' class='form-control score' value='70'>
<input name='224' type='number' class='form-control score' value='65'>
<input name='225' type='number' class='form-control score' value='87'>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rybe2azp/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Object initializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).